# Is it OK for a material designed app to have list highlight color different from accent color

Tags: color, color-scheme

Currently, I'm using blue as accent color in my material designed app.

[image]

I was wondering, from UI & UX perspective, is it OK for me to use light orange color, as list highlight color?

Or, should I make the coloring more consistent, by using light blue color as list highlight color?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look bad, but I'll vote for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is probably going to be up for debate but my opinion is that you should stick to the same accent color unless there is a reason to use another accent.

For example, let's say your accent color was green, that would be conflicting with the green used to show positive "chg %" which has causality for being green and using another accent would be justified. Here, while the "Last" values are blue, there is no specific reason for it to be blue. You could either change the values color to grey or stick to it and use a lower blue value (A-100 / A-200)

https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette